# How to transfer values set in privates of base class by an object of one derived class to an object of another derived class?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, return-value

I have my `main.cpp` like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "curve1.h"
#include "curve2.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Curve1 curve1Obj;
    Curve2 curve2Obj;

    curve1Obj.enterScores();

    curve1Obj.calcAverage();

    curve1Obj.output();

    curve1Obj.curve();

    curve1Obj.output(curve1Obj.new_getAverage1(), curve1Obj.new_getScore1());

    curve2Obj.curve();

    return 0;
}
```

Base class `Score` has two derived classes `Curve1` and `Curve2`. There are two `curve()` functions, one is in `Curve1` and other in `Curve2` classes. `getSize()` returns the value of `iSize`.

My base class header `score.h` looks like this:

```
#ifndef SCORE_H
#define SCORE_H

class Score 
{

private:

    int *ipScore;
    float fAverage;
    int iSize;

public:

    Score(

    void enterScores();
        void calcAverage();
        void output();
    void output(float, int*);

    void setSize();
    int getSize();

    void setScore();
    int *getScore();

    float getAverage();
};

#endif
```

You can see that I have used `curve1Obj` to enter scores, calculate average and output. So if I call `getSize()` function with `cuve1Obj`, it gives the right size that I took from user in `enterScores()` function. Also the result is same if I call `getSize()` in `score.cpp` definition file in any of the functions (obviously).
.....
The problem is when I call `curve()` function of `Curve2` class in main **(line 23)** with the object `curve2Obj`, it creates a new set of `ipScore`, `fAverage` and `iSize` **(i think?)** with garbage values. So when I call `getSize()` in `curve()` definition in `curve2.cpp`, it outputs the garbage.
.....
How can I cause it to return the old values that are set in `curve1.cpp`?

Here is my `curve2.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "curve2.h"

using namespace std;

void Curve2::curve()
{
    cout << "getSize() returns: " << getSize() << endl; // out comes the garbage
}
```

Can I use a function to simply put values from old to new variables? If yes then how?

Comment: Why do you want two different "curve" objects but with shared values?  Does the "curve" object have any purpose other than the `curve()` function?

Comment: @aschepler I am forced to have two different "curve" objects. One `curve1Obj` of `Curve1` class and other `curve2Obj` of `Curve2` class.

Comment: Please why are you not replying?

Comment: @rockoder Yeah!. `Curve1` "is a" `Score` and `Curve2` "is a" `Score`. Well I think I can do it using your second suggestion. But not sure how tough it is? or how much changing it will require.

Comment: (comment accidentally got deleted) Do you really need inheritance here? Does your problem definition suggests Curve1 'is a' Score (assuming public inheritance here). Similarly for Curve2. Why not create object of Score and pass it around to functions of Curve1/Curve2 for processing?

Comment: Please don't judge my Display Name and ignore my question. I was drunk at that time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically your problem can't be easily solved the way it is.
Like you said:

1 - Don't use constructors of any type.
2 - Don't use vectors.
3 - Using dynamic new and delete etc. etc.

Use the constructors or stick with what G. Samaras and Richard Hodges said. You can only solve this that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is limited information available here but I would say that your Score constructor has not initialised ipScore or iSize.

If you are hell-bent on using a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of ints for your score then at least null out the pointer in the constructor and test for null in the average function (i.e. no scores yet).

Better yet... use a std::vector of int for your scores.

Why are people still using new and delete? What the hell are they teaching in schools?

What I think you want is this:

```
#include <vector>

class Score {
public:
    Score()
    : _scores()
    , _average(0)
    { }

    void calcAverage() {
        double total = 0;
        if(auto s = _scores.size() > 0) {
            for (const auto& v : _scores)
                total += v;
            total /= s;
        }
        _average = total;
    }

    virtual void curve() = 0;

protected:
    // one of the few correct uses of 'protected' - giving limited access to data as interface to derived classes
    const std::vector<double>& scores() const {
        return _scores;
    }

    // or
    std::vector<double> copyScores() const {
        return _scores;
    }

private:
    // use doubles since you'll be doing floating point arithmetic
    std::vector<double> _scores;    
    double _average;
};

class Curve1 : public Score {
public:
    virtual void curve() override {
        // custom curve function here
        // written in terms of scores() or copyScores() if you want to make changes to the array
    }    
};

class Curve2 : public Score {
public:
    virtual void curve() override {
        // custom curve function here
        // written in terms of scores();
    }    
};
```

Comment: >What the hell are they teaching in schools? I hope you don't become a prof, because new and delete keywords, are very useful when used as they meant to!

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to resort to using new/delete in user code. It's even less sensible to use new[]/delete[] since std::vector provides a very much safer and highly optimised mechanism for the same thing. Almost the only reasonable time to use new in user code is if you're going to construct a unique_ptr or shared_ptr with the pointer returned by the call to operator new().

Comment: To Richard: Well I forgot to mention the bad news... "I cannot use a Constructor in this specific program" because those goons haven't studied it yet... Anyway it would be good if you answer just what is asked. Hope you don't mind that.

Comment: Not at all, the problem is working out what you are asking. You want to simply copy values from curve1 to curve2?

Comment: To Richard: Oh forgot to mention.. **They** also haven't studied vectors yet.. Ha ha

Comment: sure. I'll post another answer in a sec

Comment: BTW how much else information is needed? I can supply my whole program if you say..

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand inheritance. Curve1 inherits from Score. Curve2 inherits from Score.

Now see this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  int x;
};

class A : public Base {
  int a;
 public:
  void set_a(int arg) {
    a = arg;
  }
  int get_a() {
    return a;
  }
};

class B : public Base {
  int b;
 public:
  void set_b(int arg) {
    b = arg;
  }
  int get_b() {
    return b;
  }
};

int main() {
  A a_object;
  a_object.set_a(4);

  B b_object;
  b_object.set_b(a_object.get_a());

  std::cout << "a of a_object = " << a_object.get_a() << "\n";
  std::cout << "b of b_object = " << b_object.get_b() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

class A, has as members x and a. Class B has as members x and b.
When I create an instance of class A, I will two data members created internally, x and a.
When I create an instance of class A, I will two data members created internally, x and b.
But, the first x and the second are DIFFERENT. They are a different cell in the memory!

Comment: Yes yes Thanks for removing my confusion. I knew that but was a bit doubted.. Ok now what I want is HOW can I pass or equate the values of new data members as old data members. e.g. Curve1 instance had `iSize` of 2 so how can I put 2 in the `Curve2`'s `iSize`? How can I automatically transfer the new instance from old to new? If I can do this through a function, I dont mind but please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
class Score {
public:
    Score()
    : _scores(0)
    , _size(0)
    , _average(0)
    { }

    // copy constructor
    Score(const Score& rhs)
    : _scores( new double[rhs._size] )
    , _size(rhs._size)
    , _average(rhs._average)
    {
        if (_size) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < _size ; ++i) {
                _scores[i] = rhs._scores[i];
            }
        }
    }

    // ... and if copy constructor then always a copy operator

    Score& operator=(const Score& rhs) {
        // assignment in terms of copy constructor - don't repeat yourself
        Score tmp(rhs);
        swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    // pre c++11 we make our own swap. 
    // post c++11 we would make non-throwing move constructor and move-assignment operator

    void swap(Score& rhs) {
        // std::swap is guaranteed not to throw
        std::swap(_scores, rhs._scores);
        std::swap(_size, rhs._size);
        std::swap(_average, rhs._average);
    }

    ~Score()
    {
        delete[] _scores;
    }

    void calcAverage() {
        double total = 0;
        if(_size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < _size ; ++i)
                total += _scores[i];
            total /= _size;
        }
        _average = total;
    }

    virtual void curve() {};

private:
    // use doubles since you'll be doing floating point arithmetic
    double * _scores;    
    int _size;
    double _average;
};

// rmember to override the copy operators and assignment operators of derived classes
// remember to call the base class's operator
```

Comment: now that there is a copy operator you can simply write "curve2 = curve1;" in order to copy curve 1 into curve 2.